# How can I install nginx-mode into emacs?

Tags: emacs, major-mode

I want to install `nginx-mode` into emacs so that I can have highlighting and formatting of my `nginx` configuration files. What is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 8):

This requires `emacs24` or newer.

`emacs` now has a pretty good package management system. The default package repository `ELPA` has a pretty restricted set of modes and packages, so instead we'll use `MELPA` which is actively maintained and growing.

### First, install `MELPA`:

```
emacs /sudo::/etc/emacs/site-start.el
```

Paste in this code: (from https://melpa.org/#/getting-started)

```
(require 'package) ;; You might already have this line
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/"))
(when (< emacs-major-version 24)
  ;; For important compatibility libraries like cl-lib
  (add-to-list 'package-archives '("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")))
(package-initialize) ;; You might already have this line
```

Save and exit.

### Second, install `nginx-mode`

To get nginx pretty-printing and indentation, do this to install nginx-mode:

```
emacs
M-x package-list-packages RET (Type meta-key and S, then type package-list-packages and hit return)
C-s nginx RET (Type control-S to search, type nginx and hit return to find the nginx-mode package)
i (to mark it to install)
x (to execute installation of marked packages)
```

### Use `nginx-mode`

Now you can switch into nginx-mode with `M-x nginx-mode`. E.g.:

```
emacs /sudo::/etc/nginx/sites-available/default
M-x nginx-mode RET
```

You can make it recognize the sites-enabled files automatically by looking at [these instructions](https://github.com/ajc/nginx-mode#commentary).

Comment: `sudo emacs` hardly!?

Comment: @tripleee yes `sudo emacs /etc/emacs/site-start.el` is required since it's owned by root. As for the second `sudo emacs` I've corrected it. How do you install packages globally?

Comment: If you mean me personally, I tend to use my system's package manager, and create a package if one doesn't exist in the distro's repositories.

Comment: Actually, you need to use `sudo emacs` when you install the MELPA module as well, in order to have it installed into root. You need that when you're editing the nginx config files.

Comment: For editing individual files as `root`, I use Tramp's `sudo` mode, specifically to avoid running the behemoth that is Emacs completely with root privileges unless absolutely necessary

Comment: @tripleee I've updated the instructions to use Tramp's sudo mode.

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html) Emacs looks for site-start.el in directories listed in the `load-path` variable. In my case it was `/usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/site-start.el`

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use melpa:

You can download the file `nginx-mode.el` from https://github.com/ajc/nginx-mode and copy it in `~/.emacs.d/`
Then in you .emacs you can add

```el
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/")
(autoload 'nginx-mode "nginx-mode" nil t) 
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("nginx.conf\\'" . nginx-mode)) ;; or M-x nginx-mode
```